# iOS: How do I prevent scrolling when a SignaturePadView is within a UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, xamarin, uiscrollview, xamarin.ios

In my UI for my mobile program, I have a `SignaturePadView` (3rd-party component that inherits from UIView) that is within a `UIScrollView`. Whenever I try to debug the program, as soon as I put my finger inside the `SignaturePadView` and start signing, the ScrollView that it is in instead captures the input and scrolls, not allowing me to create a signature. Is there anyway of disabling the `UIScrollView`'s scrolling capability when the user touches inside the `SignaturePadView`.

Two thing that I have unsuccessfully tried:

1. Setting `ExclusiveTouch` to true on the `SignaturePadView`. For this one, it appears that the ScrollView is capturing the input before it checks on the `ExclusiveTouch`.
2. Subclassing the `UIScrollView` and overriding `TouchesShouldBegin` to turn off scrolling. This allowed me to check the `inContentView` parameter to see if it was of type `SignaturePadView`. There were two problems with this: first there are subviews inside the `SignaturePadView` that were being returned to `inContentView` rather than the `SignaturePadView`. Second, the `TouchesEnd` wasn't always firing, allowing me to turn the scrolling back on once the user was done signing.

At this point in time, I'm looking for any help I can get on this. I'm new to Xamarin and iOS development and this one last thing is preventing me from finishing my project.

Comment: If you don't want it to scroll, why do you have it in a ScrollView??

Comment: I don't want it to scroll when you have your finger inside the SignaturePadView. Otherwise, there are other controls in the scroll view that need to be accessed.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out after scrolling through some Objective-C code. I had to subclass the `ScrollView` and override `HitTest`. For anybody that runs into this problem in the future, here's the code I used.

CustomScrollView:

```
public class CustomScrollView : UIScrollView
{
    public IList<CGRect> DeadAreas { get; } = new List<CGRect>();

    public override UIView HitTest(CGPoint point, UIEvent uievent)
    {
        ScrollEnabled = DeadAreas.Any(x => x.Contains(point)) ? false : true;

        return base.HitTest(point, uievent);
    }
}
```

In my ViewController:

`_formView.DeadAreas.Add(signaturePadViewer.Frame);`

Works like a charm. Turns out my original mistake was overriding the Touch methods instead of the `HitTest` method.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to pop in and update this thread. Robert still has the correct way of going about it, I will do everyone the favour of posting the converted code from C -> Swift.

Enjoy and happy hunting!

```
class CustomScrollView: UIScrollView {

var deadAreas: [CGRect] = []

override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    if deadAreas.contains(where: { $0.contains(point) }) {
        isScrollEnabled = false
    } else {
        isScrollEnabled = true
    }
    
    return super.hitTest(point, with: event)
}
```

}